# In a Flutter Row, is there a way to center-align a child when using MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween?

Tags: flutter

I have a `Row` filling a `Container` which may have between one and three fixed-sized children. I'm using `MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween`, and when there's more than one child, it works as expected: with two children, they end up at the edges, and if there are three, two end up at the edges and one in the center.

```dart
Container(
  width: 200,
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: [
        SizedBox(width: 30, height: 20),
        SizedBox(width: 30, height: 20),
        SizedBox(width: 30, height: 20),
    ],
  ),
);
```

However, when there's only one child, it's placed at the start of the `Row`, and I'd like to have it at the center. I can certainly achieve what I need by checking the number of children beforehand and changing the `MainAxisAlignment` to `center`, but I was wondering if there's a more elegant way to combine `spaceBetween` and `center`.

Comment: What happens when you wrap the whole `Row` with a `Center` Widget?

Comment: @BilaalAbdelHassan that will not center the widgets inside the row, but the row itself.

Answer (score 1):

add  `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,` property to Raw Widget:

the code :

```
Container(
  width: 200,
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
       SizedBox(width: 30, height: 20),
    SizedBox(width: 30, height: 20),
    SizedBox(width: 30, height: 20),
],
  ),
);
```

Comment: Was going to say this!. This is the way to go.

Comment: The OP wants the single child to be centered horizontally, not vertically.

Comment: In this case Use property for Row() Widget : 
`mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,`

Comment: `spaceAround` adds unwanted space before and after the edges with two or more children.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly` (or `spaceAround`) to center the single child. To make the two children float left and right (because in `spaceEvenly` there will be extra spaces in left and right), you can add `Spacer` to the children of the `Row` (works with any number of children).

Code:

```
  List<Widget> rowChildren = [
    SizedBox(width: 30, height: 20, child: Container(color: Colors.red)),
    SizedBox(width: 30, height: 20, child: Container(color: Colors.yellow)),
    SizedBox(width: 30, height: 20, child: Container(color: Colors.green)),
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    int l = rowChildren.length;
    for (int i = 1; i < 2 * l - 1; i += 2) {
      rowChildren.insert(i, Spacer()); // adding Spacer between the two children
    }
  }
```

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
  children: rowChildren
),
```

Result (a single child):

[image: res1]

Result (two children):

[image: res2]

Result (three children):

[image: res3]

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately that's hardly easier than counting the children beforehand and changing the `mainAxisAlignment` to `center` when there's only one child as I described. In your code, for instance: `mainAxisAlignment: rowChildren.length <= 1 ? MainAxisAlignment.center : MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween`